# How to add a list of joined data in peewee?

Tags: python, peewee

I have 2 tables: dungeons and monsters.
In dungeons I have 2 records and 4 records in monsters. Each monster has a foreing key linking it to a certain dungeon.

I need to get a list of dungeons so each dungeon will have a list of it's own with all monsters that live in it.

I try to do this:

```
dungeons = list(Dungeons.select().join(Monsters))
```

It returns 4 entries:
1. dungeon 1 monster 1
2. dungeon 1 monster 2
3. dungeon 2 monster 3
4. dungeon 2 monster 4

But I need to have something like this:
1. dungeon 1 [monster1, monster2]
2. dungeon 2 [monster3, monster4]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a more efficient way: use `prefetch()`. It is documented in the ["Avoiding N+1 queries" section](http://docs.peewee-orm.com/en/latest/peewee/querying.html#avoiding-n-1-queries).

```
query = prefetch(Dungeon.select(), Monster.select())
for dungeon in query:
    print dungeon.name
    for monster in dungeon.monsters_prefetch:  # This is a list of monsters
        print '    *', monster.name
```

Answer (score 0):

Not familiar with peewee, but can you use a dictionary?

```
dungeons = {}
results = Dungeons.select().join(Monsters))
for row in results:
    if row.dungeon not in dungeons:
        dungeons[row.dungeon] = []
    dungeons[row.dungeon].append(row.monster)
```